# Reuse method code on derived class

Tags: c#, oop

I have a base class like this

```
using System;
public class Message{
  public int id {get;set;}
  //a lot of properties here
  public void print(){
    Console.WriteLine("id is " + id );

    //a lot of write lines here
  }
}
```

and a derived one like this

```
public class Comment : Message{
  public int parent_id {get;set;}
  //a lot of properties here
  public void print(){
    //???
  }
}
```

How to implement method `print()` of `Comment` which can reuse code of `Message::print()`?

Here is code on ideone https://ideone.com/9af6UM

Comment: Do you want to print `parent_id` using the base class's code ?

Comment: No, just print the common property of base and derived class, then print `parent_id` which belong to child class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, call the base class:

```
public void print()
{
    base.print();
}
```

Or override the base function:

```
// Message class:

public virtual void print()
{
    // Code...
}

// Comment class:

public override void print()
{
    // Some code...
}
```

**Update:** A C++ translation, as requested. Calling the base class:

```
public:
void print() {
    Message::print();
}
```

Overriding the base function:

```
// Message class:

public:
virtual void print() {
    // This line is the same as Console.WriteLine()
    // std::cout << "id is" << id << std::endl;

    // Code...
}

// Comment class:

public: 
void print() override {
    // Some code...
}
```

Comment: Thank, are there any equivalent ways in C++/Java?

Comment: @Tiana987642 Do you want it translated to C++ or Java?

Comment: If you know, pls add a small example :)

Comment: @Tiana987642 is that what you wanted?

Comment: @Tiana987642 Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is use the base class's implementation, then leave it out of the derived class.

```
public class Comment : Message
{
    public int parent_id {get;set;}
    //a lot of properties here
}
```

Now you can call the base `print()` method like this:

```
var comment = new Comment();
comment.print();
```

If you want to call the base class's implementation *and* do something else, you can reference the `base` class (and use the `new` keyword in the derived class to avoid a compiler warning).

```
public class Comment : Message
{
    public int parent_id {get;set;}
    //a lot of properties here

    public new void print()
    {
        base.print();
        // do additional work
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank, are there any equivalent ways in C++/Java?

Comment: Just curiosity :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve. If you simply want to call the `print()` method from a derived class then just call `print()`.

However if you want to allow different behaviour (or require behaviour) from the derived classes then what you you are looking for is to `abstract` the methods using either the [`abstract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/sf985hc5.aspx) or [`virtual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) modifiers.

`abstract` basically forces the derived class to `override` the method print()`.

`virtual` in contrast allows the derived class to optionally `override` the method.

Note that `base.` is not required and calling base.print() calls the base method in your derived class, where `print()` directly calls `print()` of the current class.

Here are a few different examples.

```
public class Message
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    //a lot of properties here
    public virtual void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("id is " + id);

        //a lot of write lines here
    }
}

public class Comment : Message
{
    public int parent_id { get; set; }

    public override void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent Id: {0}", parent_id); //print the parent id
        base.print(); //now tell the base class Message to execute print... 
    }
}

public class Message2 : Message
{

    public override void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am message two"); //print the parent id
        //note no base.print() so wont execute Message.print()
    }
}


public abstract class AbstractMessage
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public abstract void print(); //<-- note abstract therefore the derrived classes MUST implement the print() method
}

public class Message3 : AbstractMessage
{
    public override void print() //<--- must be implemented
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Iam am message 3");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank, are there any equivalent ways in C++/Java?